# testrpc How do I force development accounts to be unlocked?

Tags: testrpc, accounts, truffle-migration

Using [Truffle](http://truffleframework.com) and [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc).

I am launching `testrpc` via `testrpc --port 8545 --unlock 0`

But when I run `truffle migrate` I get

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: authentication needed: password or unlock
```

My deploy script looks like

```
const Turnip = artifacts.require('./Turnip.sol')

module.exports = (deployer, network, accounts) => {
  const superuser = accounts[0]
  console.log('Deploying to network', network, 'from', superuser)

  deployer.then(() => {
    Turnip.new({ from: superuser })
  })
}
```

All the docs I've read say that `testrpc`'s default accounts ought to be unlocked unless I specify `--secure`, but this does not appear to be true.

How do I force a test/development account to be unlocked?

Comment: Any logs from testrpc? Also, was Truffle actually connecting to another node?

Comment: no logs but I quit `testrpc` and ran `sudo lsof -i tcp:8545` and sure enough there was a docker image running an old `geth` node. D'oh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip from @l-song above I worked it out.  There was an old version of `geth` running in a Docker container that I thought I'd killed.

Running `sudo lsof -i tcp:8545` showed that the port was in use by `vpnkit` which is a thing Docker does.

So I killed that and now `truffle migrate` works.